# What rule governs this usage of the apostrophe in this case?

Tags: puntuación

I was reading the other day and came across this passage:

> En mi carrera me he planteado metas que siempre he alcanzado y **ahora'gozo** de un éxito profesional extraordinario...

I have never seen a word like **ahora'gozo** in Spanish.  What is this word, and more importantly, what is the function of the apostrophe? What rule governs its usage in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be wrong (I'm only a beginner myself) but I think it is a typo and there should be a space instead. My attempt at translation would be:

> In my career I have set goals for myself that I have always achieved and now I enjoy an extraordinary professional success.

Gozo seems to be a form of gozar.

Comment: it's right, it's a typo, and gozo is in fact the present of gozar (kind of to enjoy)

Comment: Exactly, it's just a typo.